# [error in compilation .its is a deleted function]

Tags: c++

I am getting below error:

```
2   IntelliSense: function "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 818 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\fstream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function   c:\Users\varunk\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\hashmaptest\hashmaptest\hashmaptest.cpp   12  48  hashmaptest
```

Here is my code which is showing the error:

```
// hashmaptest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Init ini;
    ifstream file("D:/test.txt", ios::in);
    ini.filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time(file);

    file.close();


    // Node shoom =  Node ("ram", 14);
    // myMap.insert(std::make_pair(Node("abc",18), 16));
    return 0;
    }


    #pragma once

    #include "targetver.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
     #include <tchar.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <string>
    #include<vector>
    #include<string>
    #include <bitset>
    #include <utility>
    #include <fstream>
    using  namespace std;

     class FilterKeys
     {
      public:
        FilterKeys(string a, int b)
         {
         name = a;
         time = b;
        }
        string name;
        int time;

       };
      class HashKey
     {
     public:
     size_t operator() (FilterKeys const& key) const
     {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(key.name) ^
            (std::hash<int>()(key.time) << 1);

      }
      };

     class EqualTo
      {
      public :
      bool operator()(const FilterKeys& lhs, const FilterKeys& rhs) const
      {
         return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.time == rhs.time;
      }

      };
     class Init {
      unordered_multimap<FilterKeys, int, HashKey, EqualTo> _myMap;
      public:
      void  filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time(ifstream file)
       {

         string location;
         int time, addId;
         if (!file)
             cerr << "Cant open " << endl;

         while (file >> location >> time >> addId)
         {

             if (_myMap.count(FilterKeys(location, time)) < 3)
                 _myMap.insert(std::make_pair(FilterKeys(location, time),     addId));

         }

     }
     unordered_multimap<FilterKeys, int, HashKey, EqualTo> getHashMap()
     {
         return _myMap;
     }

     };
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @varunkumar Looks like you're trying to copy an `std::ifstream`. Have you tried making `filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time()` take a reference instead? Also, don't trust IntelliSense too much.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't call the copy constructor of ifstream - it doesn't have one.

You need to change:

```
 void  filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time(ifstream file)
```

to

```
  void  filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time(ifstream& file)
```

This will mean that you pass a *reference* to the file object (rather than a copy).  You need to be aware that passing a reference means that changes you make in the called function will be seen in `main`.

In other cases, you may want to pass a reference, but forbid the called function from making changes to the object.  In that case you would write:

```
 void  filterng_three_addId_on_location_and_time(const ifstream& file)
```

(a *reference to const*).  That won't work here, because all the input functions modify the `ifstream` object, so you would get a compiler error when you called them.